# Given a field extension $K\colon F$, $K$ is an $F$-vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, field-theory, terminology, definition

I'm having a hard time understanding fields. Could someone help with the following

I need to show that if $F$ $\subseteq$ $K$ are both fields and addition and multiplication on F are the restrictions of addition and multiplication on $K$($F$ is a subfield of $K$) then $K$ can be thought of as an $F$-vector space with addition just the addition on $K$ and scalar multiplication by elements of $F$ simply multiplication by elements of $F$.

What does it mean when by 'F-vector space'?

Would I have to check all the fields axioms?

Comment: "What does it mean when by 'F-vector space'?" - Do you know the definition of vector space?

Comment: @GitGud yeah but I'm not sure what it means with the F- in front

Comment: Please state the definition of vector space without spelling out the axioms. Tell me something like "A vector space is _________ which satisfies certain axioms".

Comment: A collection of vectors which is closed under addition and scalar multiplication

Comment: @llll: No, that is not the definition of a vector space. It assumes that we already know what "addition" and "scalar multiplication" means, but in fact those two things are _part of_ the definition of "vector space". Go find your linear algebra textbook and look up the _actual_ definition.

Comment: (It could be the definition of a _subspace_, though).

Comment: A vector space is a $5$-tuple $(V,\mathbb F, +_V,+_{\mathbb F}, \cdot)$ where $(V,+)$ is a commutative group, $(\mathbb F, +_{\mathbb F}, \cdot)$ is a field and a few axioms which do not matter at the moment. It's common to refer to this $5$-tuple simply by $V$ and since it depends on the field $\mathbb F$, one uses the terminology 'vector space $V$ over $\mathbb F$' or '$V$ is an $\mathbb F$-vector space'.

Comment: @GitGud Thanks, I've never seen that definition/notation of a vector space before. Makes more sense now

Comment: @lllll It's one way of putting things. The one I've seen the most goes something like "Given a non-empty set $V$, a field $\mathbb F$, a binary operation $+_V$ on $V$, binary operations $+_{\mathbb F}, \cdot$ on $\mathbb F$ which satisfy the following axioms (...), one says $V$is a vector space over $\mathbb F$."

Comment: @GitGud Sorry to bother you again, but going back to the showing the original problem, would I just say, since F is a subfield of K, F inherits field operations from K? Thanks

Comment: I don't know. That depends on the level of detail required. I would say that's probably enough. It's no bother.

Answer (score 1):

Vector space is an abelian group first: that is the group of vectors.
But that is not enough. We also need to have a concept of scalar multiplication. These scalars are 'aliens': they are from another object, a field.
ANd there are various conditions the alien field's addition and multiplication has to satisfy to interact 'compatibly' with the addition operation of vectors.

The vectos space is called $F$-vector space if that alien field is F.